# php return empty array using angular js?

Tags: javascript, php, html, function

i want get arrayobject from php file using angular js, this works but array   does not display content in the browser:

my php file:

```
<?php

include_once '../DAO/DAOadmin.php';

$list = DAOadmin::All();

$json = json_encode($list);
echo $json;
```

angular js:

```
scope.all = function(){
       $http.get('/App/Test/getAll.php').then(function(data){
                $scope.model = data;
            });
}
```

the network show this:

[image: result with echo $json]

Also i tired using print_r but not work:

[image: result with print_r]

Comment: its sound like the problem come from php and not from Angular you need to check your php scrip an see if the script return something cause as long as the script doesn't return anything the Ajax request wont return anything also

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong with the script and try to run the php script through the browser and see the results. Then you will probably get the answer.

look like $list is not an array it could be a pdo object, convert pdo object to array and assign it to $list.

Comment: Hi, i run the php script and the response is the same

Comment: dump the $list variable and see what is the result?

Comment: Exactly the same as the photo's

Comment: Then there is a problem in $list = DAOadmin::All(); try to explore this function and understand why is this return something like that.

Comment: Now works! using print_r($list) but with print_r(json_encode($list)) not work... but now i cant  get acces to array values from browser :/ do you help me ?

check this image with result:

http://imgur.com/a/ZJaiJ

Comment: print_r(json_encode($list)) this is wrong. I said you to print_r($list) the results and see the results just to verify that data is coming properly from the $list = DAOadmin::All(); code. remove all the print_r functions and get the code as it is.

Comment: include_once '../DAO/DAOadmin.php';

$list = DAOadmin::All();

$json = json_encode($list);
echo $json;

Comment: ok, using $json = json_encode($list);   echo $json, the result that is:  {"0":{},"1":{},"2":{}}..... when use print_r($list) show results but cant acces the values http://imgur.com/a/ZJaiJ

Comment: look like $list is not an array it is a pdo object, convert pdo object to array and assign it to list.

Comment: Ok i solved problem: in the pdo method i was usin arrayobject to save values, now i use $arr = array();.... then in foreach   arr[] = $row  thanks